# React Native: R is not a function in react-navigation-drawer.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am really really new to react native and I designed an app with builderx.io and export(not directly) to expo.dev IDE and when it run it gives some errors, which I can't find what it is, please help me,
my code can be found in [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev/@rezsat/bw-colorizer).

here is the error i got :

```
R is not a function
value@react-navigation-drawer.js:3:35720
Ni@[snack internals]
Mi@[snack internals]
ms@[snack internals]
dl@[snack internals]
sl@[snack internals]
Zs@[snack internals]
Ja/<@[snack internals]
t.unstable_runWithPriority@[snack internals]
qa@[snack internals]
Ja@[snack internals]
Ha@[snack internals]
Vs@[snack internals]
xi@[snack internals]
handleFinishLoading@App.js.js:63:22
onFinish@App.js.js:42:25
value/<@expo-app-loading.js:3:4933
s@expo-app-loading.js:3:6421
c/i._invoke</<@expo-app-loading.js:3:6175
b/</<@expo-app-loading.js:3:6780
s@expo-app-loading.js:3:6421
n@expo-app-loading.js:3:6917
n/<@expo-app-loading.js:3:7061
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Expo version to "40.0.0" and the problem will be solved